# iTunes and change a resource file on an app without compile again with xcode

Tags: xcode, resources, itunes

I have a scenario to fill for a client: he want to have an ad-hoc app, were he can
change a file (in this case an .xml file) when he want, without using xcode (because they dont
have any mac). I created this file, but when I change something inside, copy to itunes again
and I try to install, it says that the resources has been modified and it stops.

Is any solution or the client must have xcode, compile every time this file change and reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a dynamic XML file contained inside an iPhone application due to code signing restrictions. Can you have the XML hosted on a server and the phone app downloads the latest XML periodically or on each start? Retrieving the XML is really straightforward using iOS.

Comment: The client bought the source code, so no problem anymore, thanks btw for the reply!